# Issue in Conversion of 6*6 array into 3*3 array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to solve the hacker rank question and [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/2d-array/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=arrays) is the question link.

In the question, I am converting (6 * 6) array into 3 * 3 array and passed to other function. In the conversion of 3*3 array, arrray structure desired by question requirements is not obtained

I debugged with console.log statement and googled for further steps. I am stuck with structuring array according to question requirements

Still, one test case passed on running the code in hacker rank. can you help me  figure out the mistakes?

code snippet:

```js
function getSubArray(arr, tlc, size) {
  var a = new Array();
  for (var i = tlc[0]; i < size + tlc[0]; i++) {
    var b = new Array();
    for (var j = tlc[0]; j < size + tlc[0]; j++) {
      //if ((i==tlc[0]) || (i == tlc[0]+size)-1)
      b.push(arr[i][j]);
      //}
      if (i == tlc[0] + 1) {
        //b[i][tlc[1]] = 0;
        b[i].pop();
        b[i].shift();
        //b[i][tlc[size + tlc[1]]] = 0;
      }
      //console.log(b);
    }
    a.push(b);
  }
  console.log(a);
  return a;
};
```

Full code:

```js
/*
  Let's simply represent this entire problem space differently. 
  Let's reconceive homogeneous, higher-order, JS arrays as two-
  dimensional, algebraic arrays instead of JS arrays, since JS 
  is not natively well-suited for this. 

  First, a few utility functions for handling arrays...
*/

// calculate and return the sums of all the desired subarrays - 
// relies on functions that treat JS arrays *differently*;
// current implementations assumes that square subarrays of shape 
// {size x size} are desired
function calcSubSums(arr, size) {
  var sums = new Array();
  console.log(arr.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length - size + 1; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length - size + 1; j++) {
      sums.push(reduce(ravel(getSubArray(arr, [i, j], size))));
    }
  }
  return sums;
};

// for an array, arr, return subarray that starts at the top-left-
// corner indexes tlc (top-row-index, left-column-index) for an 
// extent of size on each dimension
function getSubArray(arr, tlc, size) {
  var a = new Array();
  for (var i = tlc[0]; i < size + tlc[0]; i++) {
    var b = new Array();
    for (var j = tlc[0]; j < size + tlc[0]; j++) {
      //if ((i==tlc[0]) || (i == tlc[0]+size)-1)
      b.push(arr[i][j]);
      //}
      if (i == tlc[0] + 1) {
        //b[i][tlc[1]] = 0;
        b[i].pop();
        b[i].shift();
        //b[i][tlc[size + tlc[1]]] = 0;
      }
      //console.log(b);
    }
    a.push(b);
  }
  console.log(a);
  return a;
};

// convert a higher dimensional array into one-dimensional array 
// that contains all of its elements, unpacking from top-to-bottom, 
// left-to-right
function ravel(arr, flat) {
  // If flat - accumulator array - not yet defined, create it.
  if ('undefined' == typeof flat) flat = new Array();
  // If arg is an array, iterate over the elements in index order.
  if (isArray(arr)) {
    // Call self recursively to get elements or process next, 
    // outermost level of nesting.
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      ravel(arr[i], flat);
    }
  }
  // Otherwise, just add simple element to accumulator.
  else flat.push(arr);
  // Return accumulated values.
  return flat;
};

// return a Boolean indicator of whether the argument is a JS array
function isArray(a) {
  if ('undefined' == typeof a) {
    return false
  };
  return -1 != a.constructor.toString().indexOf('Array');
};

// place the operator {op} between the elements of a and evaluate the 
// entire, resulting expression
function reduce(a, op) {
  // Set default op (add/concatenate), if not given.
  //console.log(a);
  if ('undefined' == typeof op) op = '+';
  // Initialize command to evaluate.
  var cmd = '';
  // Compose command string - concatenate each element with op.
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    cmd += a[i] + op;
  }
  // Remove, extraneous, trailing instance of op and return evaluation.
  //console.log(cmd.length);
  //console.log(op.length);
  return eval(cmd.substring(0, cmd.length - op.length));
};

// now let's test it...
window.onload = function() {
  // declare the test array
  var array = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0],
    [10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0],
    [10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0]
  ];
  // calculate all of the sums of 3x3 subset arrays of our test array 
  // and write the totals to the console
  console.log(calcSubSums(array, 3));
};
```

Comment: Please put the problem description here, not just a link. Our questions should not be dependent on other sites.

Comment: The snippet gives error

Comment: I suggest you to directly sum required places using nested `for`, there is no need for subarray and all. Check the Constraints which is very clear

Comment: *"arrray structure desired by question requirements"*: the challenge you refer to does not require an array structure as output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is to calculate the maximum sum of values in the hourglass position, so there is no point in splitting to multiple sub-arrays.

```js
function calcSubSums(arr) {
  let max = -Infinity
  for (let x = 0; x <= arr.length - 3; x++) {
    for (let y = 0; y <= arr.length - 3; y++) {
      // sum the top row
      let sum = arr[x][y] + arr[x][y + 1] + arr[x][y + 2]

      // sum the middle row
      sum += arr[x + 1][y + 1]

      // sum the bottom row
      sum += arr[x + 2][y] + arr[x + 2][y + 1] + arr[x + 2][y + 2]

      max = Math.max(max, sum)
    }
  }
  return max
}


var array = [
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0],
  [10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0],
  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  [5, 5, 5, 0, 0, 0],
  [10, 10, 10, 0, 0, 0]
];

console.log(calcSubSums(array));
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply... the code worked...your suggestions are really helpful to me

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Javascript is not python, so in order to solve this, you'd have to extend the standard library first. But once this is over with, the rest of the program is easy:

```js
// "library"

function* iter(it) {
    yield* it;
}

function* zip(...its) {
    its = its.map(iter);
    while (true) {
        let rs = its.map(it => it.next());
        if (rs.some(r => r.done))
            break;
        yield rs.map(r => r.value);
    }
}

function* slice(it, n) {
    for (let x of it) {
        if (--n < 0)
            yield x;
    }
}

function sum(it) {
    let s = 0;
    for (let x of it)
        s += x;
    return s;
}

function max(it) {
    let s = -Infinity;
    for (let x of it)
        s = x > s ? x : s;
    return s;
}

// "your program"

function* triples(a) {
    yield* zip(a, slice(a, 1), slice(a, 2));
}

function* sums(mat) {
    for (let rows of triples(mat))
        for (let [s0, s1, s2] of zip(...rows.map(triples)))
            yield sum(s0) + s1[1] + sum(s2);
}

function solution(mat) {
    return max(sums(mat));
}

// "test"

let test = [
    [-9, -9, -9, 1, 1, 1,],
    [0, -9, 0, 4, 3, 2,],
    [-9, -9, -9, 1, 2, 3,],
    [0, 0, 8, 6, 6, 0,],
    [0, 0, 0, -2, 0, 0,],
    [0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 0,],
];

console.log(solution(test));
```

The key function is `triples`, which turns `1 2 3 4 5 6` into `123 234 345 456`. We apply it to the matrix itself, giving us sliding groups of three rows, and then again to each row in a group, giving us 3x3 sub-matrices. All that's left is to sum them and find the max.

Of course, this could be also solved trivially with indexes:

```js
let m = [
    [-9, -9, -9, 1, 1, 1,],
    [0, -9, 0, 4, 3, 2,],
    [-9, -9, -9, 1, 2, 3,],
    [0, 0, 8, 6, 6, 0,],
    [0, 0, 0, -2, 0, 0,],
    [0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 0,],
];


let len = m.length;

let sums = [];

for (let r = 0; r < len - 2; r++)
    for (let c = 0; c < len - 2; c++)
        sums.push(
            m[r][c] + m[r][c + 1] + m[r][c + 2] +
            m[r + 1][c + 1] +
            m[r + 2][c] + m[r + 2][c + 1] + m[r + 2][c + 2]
        );


console.log(Math.max(...sums))
```

but hey, what's the fun in that?

Comment: 2 test case failed, try using the link in question

Comment: [here](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/2d-array/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D=arrays)

Comment: @AswinKumar: yep, which matrix exactly doesn't work?

Comment: This one `[[-1,-1,0,-9,-2,-2],[-2,-1,-6,-8,-2,-5],[-1,-1,-1,-2,-3,-4],[-1,-9,-2,-4,-4,-5],[-7,-3,-3,-2,-9,-9],[-1,-3,-1,-2,-4,-5]]`

Comment: @georg... thanks a lot for your reply... the code worked...your suggestions are really helpful to me

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear in your question if you are trying to solve this in a particular way as an exercise or just solve it. It seem like you have a lot of code for what amounts to two loops. I apologize, if I'm missing the point, but thought I'd post this as a straightforward solution that basically steps through the array row by row and column by column:

```js
let test = [
  [-9, -9, -9, 1, 1, 1,],
  [0, -9, 0, 4, 3, 2,],
  [-9, -9, -9, 1, 2, 3,],
  [0, 0, 8, 6, 6, 0,],
  [0, 0, 0, -2, 0, 0,],
  [0, 0, 1, 2, 4, 0,],
];

function maxBrick(test){
  // helper sum function
  const sum = (arr) => arr.reduce((s, n) => s + n)
  let max 

  for (let row = 0; row < test.length - 2; row++ ){
    for(let col = 0; col < test[row].length - 2; col++){
      // slice out "brick"
      let brick = test          
                  .slice(row, row+3)
                  .map(r => r.slice(col, col+3))

      // get bricks hourglass sum
      let curr_sum = sum([
                      sum(brick[0]),
                      brick[1][1], 
                      sum(brick[2]) 
                    ])
      // set max if bigger
      if (max === undefined || curr_sum > max) max = curr_sum
    }
  }
  return max
}

console.log(maxBrick(test))
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply... the code worked....your suggestions are really helpful to me

Answer (score 0):

The errors are in `getSubArray`:

- The index at the inner loop is wrong. It should be `tlc[1]` instead of `tlc[0]`
- You intend to remove 2 items when at the second row, but:

  - This should not happen in the inner loop
  - This goes against the generic nature of the function. Think of what this does when size is 2 or 8? Possibly you could do such removal in all rows except the first and the last. That way is stays somewhat generic
  - `b[i]` is not an array, so calling `pop` or `shift` on it will not work
  - `i` is an index in `arr`, not `b`, so with `b[i]` you'll point to the wrong, or even non-existing element. You should just apply `pop` and `shift` on `b` itself.

Here is the corrected function:

```
function getSubArray(arr, tlc, size) {
  var a = new Array();
  for (var i = tlc[0]; i < size + tlc[0]; i++) {
    var b = new Array();
    for (var j = tlc[1]; j < size + tlc[1]; j++) { // index must be 1
      b.push(arr[i][j]);
    }
    if ((i - tlc[0]) % (size-1)) { // A bit more generic; out of inner loop
      b.pop(); // No index
      b.shift();
    }
    a.push(b);
  }
  console.log(a);
  return a;
}
```

There are more things to say about your code:

- Using `eval` is not-done. It also impacts performance. To sum up the values in an array, you would use the built-in `reduce` method: `a.reduce((b, c) => b+c, 0)`
- JavaScript recently got Array methods like `.flat()`, which with the appropriate argument can do what `ravel` does
- JavaScript has `Array.isArray`, which makes your own `isArray` unnecessary
- You don't need to call the `Array` constructor. Just use a literal: `[]`

Comment: @trincot...thanks a lot for your reply...the code worked...your suggestions are really helpful to me

Comment: Yes, I thought, let's answer the question *"can you help me figure out the mistakes?"* ... Not sure why you accepted an answer that did not answer this, though ;-P